# Images get squeezed on orientation-change

Tags: android, layout

I have used a grid view where store the image from web service.
But my problem is when my device orientation is changed from **portrait** to **landscape** then the images get squeezed.
When I scrolled then `getview` is called so images are resized.

Comment: Can you show some code and maybe ScreenShots.

Comment: Then just call NotifyDataSetChanged() in onResume().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Picasso to fit your image to imageview and change the imageview property to

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgvw_eventmage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />
```

You set the picasso like this

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(imgurl).fit().into(imgvw_eventmage, new Callback() {

   @Override
   public void onSuccess() {
    allgrouplistprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }

   @Override
   public void onError() {

    allgrouplistprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imgvw_eventmage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank);
   }
  });
```

If you have any query you can ask.Enjoy :)